# How do I compare two files in Ruby 1.9?

Tags: ruby, ruby-1.9, file-comparison

In Ruby 1.8, I would call [File.compare()](http://stdlib.rubyonrails.org/libdoc/ftools/rdoc/classes/File.html#M000765) from the "ftools" library to easily compare the contents of two files.

However, in Ruby 1.9, "ftools" is replaced by "fileutils", which doesn't have a "compare" method. What's the equivalent call?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Ahh, the method has been renamed to [compare_file](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.3/libdoc/fileutils/rdoc/FileUtils.html#method-c-compare_file) in FileUtils.

There's also an alias of "[cmp](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.3/libdoc/fileutils/rdoc/FileUtils.html#method-c-cmp)" in both versions.

Answer (score 20):

Old question, but I just got here from google. `identical?` is available for those who like me prefer that coding style.

```
FileUtils.identical?(exp, act)
```

Comment: It worked like a charm for me, I used it to make a comparison in RSpec context

Comment: if file1 is identical to file2 you can write expect(FileUtils).to be_identical(file1, file2)

Comment: **Don't confuse this with `File#identical?`**, which only checks, if the files are actually the same physical files on the drive.